# Remove Merged Rows from Original Dataframe in R

Tags: r, merge, data-cleaning

I am working in R and I have two data frames. My goal is to merge them based on two columns and then remove whichever rows were merged from the first data frame. So, for example, if I started with something like the following:

```
A: x y z
   1 2 3
   4 5 6

B: q x y
   7 1 2
   3 8 9
```

After merging based on (x,y) and removing matching rows from A, I would want to end up with:

```
A: x y z
   4 5 6

C: q x y z
   7 1 2 3
```

Is there a way to add a "flag" or "remove" column to A that evaluates to true wherever the rows match with a row in B? What is an efficient way to do this other than looping through A and B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dplyr` library offers several joining options.
If you use `inner_join`, you will return rows that match both in A and B.

```
inner_join(A,B,by=c("x","y"))
x y z q
1 2 3 7
```

If you use `anti_join`, you will return only the rows that match in A and not in B:

```
anti_join(A,B,by=c("x","y"))
x y z
4 5 6
```

Comment: Thank you for the details! I will try that approach.